# Web API Custom ModelBinder Required child object

Tags: asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, model-binding

I am using ASP.NET Web API 2,and I'm trying to validate this child object from my request

the [DataAnnotation Required] is working well on my  parent object,
but its not working when the a [required] property in child object is missing.

below the sample of my model

In the below posted data, when I'm trying to insert in the table [Users] using the below request (missed the DeviceName in the child object Devices), the [Devices] is not validated against the Data annotations. This means that I don't got an error in the ModelState indicates that the DeviceName field is required.
Note: The User object is model binding and validation is working good.

Also the custom ModelBinder is not fired

Model:

```
[Serializable]
[Table("Users")]
public partial class Users
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Column("UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserDevice> UserDevices { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[Table("Users_Devices")]
public partial class UserDevice
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("DeviceName")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    [Column("DeviceDescription")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    [Column("UserID", TypeName = "int")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([ModelBinder(typeof(APIUsersModelBinder))] Users user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        _db.Users.Add(user);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created(user);
    }
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "UserName":"TestUser",
     "Devices":
        [{
            "DeviceDescription":"Description"
        }]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking. You are talking about Departments, but I don't see that in your code at all.

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: I edited the child class name. The post data of the request contains a sub object (Devices), the validation of the (Devices) entity is not fired, as the [DeviceName] is not exist while it's required.
The Question is: I want (Devices) to be validated when submitting the mentioned request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search I found that there is no other way than firing the validations manually as mentioned in this link

http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2011/12/23/Custom+Recursive+Model+Validation+In+NET+Using+Data+Annotations.aspx